# How to manipulate string and lead zero

Tags: arrays, bash, sed, grep, cut

before I can explain the problem I've to make some clarification about it.

I'm changing a vpn script for my dd-wrt router. Please note that this router don't have bash so I installed it via entware, like all command like sed grep cut, and so on.

Now, my script call another script and collect data from it.
The output from the called script is that

```
./nordvpn-server-find -l fr

Looking for servers located in FR with current capacity lower than 30%...

fr27.nordvpn.com     9%
fr104.nordvpn.com    10%
fr169.nordvpn.com    10%
fr25.nordvpn.com     10%
fr37.nordvpn.com     10%
fr80.nordvpn.com     11%
fr98.nordvpn.com     11%
fr114.nordvpn.com    12%
fr127.nordvpn.com    13%
fr16.nordvpn.com     13%
fr133.nordvpn.com    14%
fr41.nordvpn.com     14%
fr50.nordvpn.com     14%
fr62.nordvpn.com     14%
fr67.nordvpn.com     14%
fr19.nordvpn.com     15%
fr30.nordvpn.com     15%
fr31.nordvpn.com     15%
fr46.nordvpn.com     15%
fr84.nordvpn.com     15%
```

As you can see is a list of server with current load, this list is formatted in columns, so in my script I take only the very first 3 server of that list with this command

```
declare -a SERVERDIRS  # declare an array
SERVERDIRS+=($($COMMANDSPATH/bash $JFFSPATH/nordvpn-server-find -l it \
    | $COMMANDSPATH/head -6 | $COMMANDSPATH/tail -3 | $COMMANDSPATH/awk '{print $1}'))  

echo
echo ${SERVERDIRS[*]}  # echo all the elements of the array
echo "number of element in array" ${#SERVERDIRS[@]}
echo "first element in array" ${SERVERDIRS[0]}
echo "last element in array" ${SERVERDIRS[${#SERVERDIRS[@]}-1]}
```

Please note that $COMMANDSPATH and $JFFSPATH are my path variable to point to the right place. As you can see, If I'm not wrong I put the very first 3 server into an array and then I can manipulate it, here the output about the array creation

```
#vpn rnd

fr27.nordvpn.com fr104.nordvpn.com fr169.nordvpn.com
number of element in array 3
first element in array fr27.nordvpn.com
last element in array fr169.nordvpn.com
```

All looks good right now, the array is 3 elements and so on

So my expectation is to extract all the data before the very first "." and then format it to have it with 4 digits, for example
fr27.nordvpn.com -> have to became -> fr0027 and so on.

So I tried with this approach
https://repl.it/@jorman/JovialAngryWebpages
that actually works, on repl.it but I don't know why, on bash don't!
See the ouput of this solution

```
    vpn rnd
    first var
    econd var 36
    1
    80
    third var
    
    irst var
    econd var 36
    1
    129
    third var
    
    irst var
    econd var 36
    1
    37
    third var
```

Seems there's a strange error, missing char "irst" instead first and other, so I run it in debug mode, see the log

```
+ declare -a SERVERDIRS
+ SERVERDIRS+=($($COMMANDSPATH/bash $JFFSPATH/nordvpn-server-find -l fr | $COMMANDSPATH/head -6 | $COMMANDSPATH/tail -3 | $COMMANDSPATH/awk '{print $1}'))
++ /opt/bin/head -6
++ /opt/bin/bash /jffs//nordvpn-server-find -l fr
++ /opt/bin/tail -3
++ /opt/bin/awk '{print $1}'
+ for i in "${SERVERDIRS[@]}"
++ /opt/bin/sed 's/\..*//'
++ echo 'fr188.nordvpn.com'
++ /opt/bin/cut -c1-2
+ aaa='
pt/bin/sed 's/\..*//'
++ echo 'fr188.nordvpn.com'
++ /opt/bin/grep -oP '\d+'
+ bbb='36
1
188'
++ printf %04d 36 1 188
+ bbbmod=003600010188
+ ccc='
cho 'first var
irst var
cho 'second var 36
1
188'
second var 36
1
188
+ echo 'third var
hird var
cho

+ for i in "${SERVERDIRS[@]}"
++ echo 'fr193.nordvpn.com'
++ /opt/bin/cut -c1-2
++ /opt/bin/sed 's/\..*//'
+ aaa='
pt/bin/sed 's/\..*//'
++ /opt/bin/grep -oP '\d+'
++ echo 'fr193.nordvpn.com'
+ bbb='36
1
193'
++ printf %04d 36 1 193
+ bbbmod=003600010193
+ ccc='
cho 'first var
irst var
cho 'second var 36
1
193'
second var 36
1
193
+ echo 'third var
hird var
cho

+ for i in "${SERVERDIRS[@]}"
++ echo 'fr194.nordvpn.com'
++ /opt/bin/sed 's/\..*//'
++ /opt/bin/cut -c1-2
+ aaa='
cho 'fr194.nordvpn.com'
++ /opt/bin/grep -oP '\d+'
++ /opt/bin/sed 's/\..*//'
+ bbb='36
1
194'
++ printf %04d 36 1 194
+ bbbmod=003600010194
+ ccc='
cho 'first var
irst var
cho 'second var 36
1
194'
second var 36
1
194
+ echo 'third var
hird var
cho

+ echo

+ echo 'fr188.nordvpn.com' 'fr193.nordvpn.com' 'fr194.nordvpn.com'
fr188.nordvpn.com fr193.nordvpn.com fr194.nordvpn.com
+ echo 'number of element in array' 3
number of element in array 3
+ echo 'first element in array' 'fr188.nordvpn.com'
first element in array fr188.nordvpn.com
+ echo 'last element in array' 'fr194.nordvpn.com'
last element in array fr194.nordvpn.com
+ echo

+ echo 'fr188.nordvpn.com'
+ /opt/bin/sed 's/\..*//'
+ /opt/bin/sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
361188
+ exit
```

If you notice seems that 3, 6 and 1 are from the code

```
++ /opt/bin/head -6
++ /opt/bin/bash /jffs//nordvpn-server-find -l fr
++ /opt/bin/tail -3
++ /opt/bin/awk '{print $1}'
```

I can't explain what is happening.

I miss some from the code? There's a better way to extract info from the array, I need the array?

Comment: MSWin line ends in the input?

Comment: If you mean (CR+LF) instead of (LF), I just checked all the script, are all LF, and I don't see any ^M char at the end of the line

Comment: Please post your code corresponding to the debug output.

Comment: Can you simplify your question to clearly show **the input** and **the expected output** given that input? I think I know what the input is (the list of domains and percentages, right?) but I can't find the expected output given that input and I feel like there's a lot of other information in there that's just distracting from whatever it is you're asking for help to do.

Answer (score 0):

this might work (if I understand correctly what you want to achieve).

```
echo "
Looking for servers located in FR with current capacity lower than 30%...

fr27.nordvpn.com     9%
fr104.nordvpn.com    10%
fr169.nordvpn.com    10%
fr25.nordvpn.com     10%
fr37.nordvpn.com     10%
fr80.nordvpn.com     11%
fr98.nordvpn.com     11%
fr114.nordvpn.com    12%
fr127.nordvpn.com    13%
fr16.nordvpn.com     13%
fr133.nordvpn.com    14%
fr41.nordvpn.com     14%
fr50.nordvpn.com     14%
fr62.nordvpn.com     14%
fr67.nordvpn.com     14%
fr19.nordvpn.com     15%
fr30.nordvpn.com     15%
fr31.nordvpn.com     15%
fr46.nordvpn.com     15%
fr84.nordvpn.com     15%
" | awk 'BEGIN { counter=0; } /nordvpn.com/ { split($1, a, /\./); print a[1]; counter++; if ( counter == 3 ) exit; }'
fr27
fr104
fr169
```

Obviously in your case you should not use `echo` but use the output of the script directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear so lets start by cleaning up your shell script and see where we get to. Given this input:

```
$ cat file

Looking for servers located in FR with current capacity lower than 30%...

fr27.nordvpn.com     9%
fr104.nordvpn.com    10%
fr169.nordvpn.com    10%
fr25.nordvpn.com     10%
fr37.nordvpn.com     10%
fr80.nordvpn.com     11%
fr98.nordvpn.com     11%
fr114.nordvpn.com    12%
fr127.nordvpn.com    13%
fr16.nordvpn.com     13%
fr133.nordvpn.com    14%
fr41.nordvpn.com     14%
fr50.nordvpn.com     14%
fr62.nordvpn.com     14%
fr67.nordvpn.com     14%
fr19.nordvpn.com     15%
fr30.nordvpn.com     15%
fr31.nordvpn.com     15%
fr46.nordvpn.com     15%
fr84.nordvpn.com     15%
```

then to do what it currently does your script should be written as this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
serverDirs=( $(
        cat file |
        awk 'NR>3{print $1} NR==6{exit}'
) )

printf '\n'
printf '%s\n' "${serverDirs[*]}"         # print all the elements of the array
printf 'number of element in array %s\n' "${#serverDirs[@]}"
printf 'first element in array %s\n'     "${serverDirs[0]}"
printf 'last element in array %s\n'      "${serverDirs[${#serverDirs[@]}-1]}"
$
$ ./tst.sh

fr27.nordvpn.com fr104.nordvpn.com fr169.nordvpn.com
number of element in array 3
first element in array fr27.nordvpn.com
last element in array fr169.nordvpn.com
```

Obviously I'm using `cat file` in place of `$COMMANDSPATH/bash $JFFSPATH/nordvpn-server-find -l it` since I have the input for the rest of the script saved in `file` and I don't have `nordvpn-server-find` and I didn't prefix the awk command with `$COMMANDSPATH/` since I don't have that variable set.

Beyond that - you do not need head + tail plus pipes when you're using awk, you should not use all upper case for non-exported variable names to avoid clashing with exported ones, printf is more portable than echo, and you must always quote shell variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not doing so. So, I've taken care of all of that.

Now, what else do you need? I don't see the expected output in your question and all I could see hinting about what the expected output might be is `So my expectation is to extract all the data before the very first "." and then format it to have it with 4 digits, for example fr27.nordvpn.com -> have to became -> fr0027 and so on.` - if that's all you need then we can just change the awk script to do that:

```
$ cat tst.sh
serverDirs=( $(
        cat file |
        awk '
            NR>3 {
                alpha = num = rest = $1
                sub(/[0-9].*/,"",alpha)
                gsub(/^[^0-9]+|\..*/,"",num)
                sub(/^[^.]+/,"",rest)
                num = sprintf("%04d",num)
                print alpha num rest
            }
            NR==6 { exit }
        '
) )

printf '\n'
printf '%s\n' "${serverDirs[*]}"         # print all the elements of the array
printf 'number of element in array %s\n' "${#serverDirs[@]}"
printf 'first element in array %s\n'     "${serverDirs[0]}"
printf 'last element in array %s\n'      "${serverDirs[${#serverDirs[@]}-1]}"
$
$ ./tst.sh

fr0027.nordvpn.com fr0104.nordvpn.com fr0169.nordvpn.com
number of element in array 3
first element in array fr0027.nordvpn.com
last element in array fr0169.nordvpn.com
```

Is that what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I read some good code that I'll implement into this little script.

But I found the problem:
Looking through the log and the debug I see a code like this

```
[\033
```

And in my mind I was sure I had already seen it!

The nordvpn script that return the server loads, write the output with tput, so the output is colored! So happen that all this information jump into the code and when all the logics cut grep and parse all the information, the "color code" are still in place and make the difference!

So I disabled the colored output and all works like a charm!